# Error calling template Function C++

Tags: c++, templates

I have a Problem when i can a function which has a parameter which has three template parameters.
When I want to compile my code g++ says, that the function was note declared.

Function:

```
double FunctionXY(
    const Object<float, vectorType, T> obj, //In
    const double d)
{
....
return d;
}
```

Where I call it:

```
FunctionXY(&H, d);
```

Constructor of H:

```
Object<float, vectorType, T> Obj("Object");
```

I also tried to give the whole function a template and then put those template variables in the template parameters of obj.

Anyone has an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you passing a pointer to H instead of just the object by value?

Comment: show the complete unaltered error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function takes an `Object` by value. You're trying to pass a pointer.

Either pass a value:

```
FunctionXY(H,d);
```

or change (or overload) the function to take a pointer

```
double FunctionXY(
    const Object<float, vectorType, T> * obj, //In
    const double d)  //                ^
```

Comment: I find it unlikely that T is an actual type that can be used in this context.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe: I've no idea how you figured out what has and hasn't been declared in this context but, if it weren't, there'd be far more errors.

Comment: yeah, thanks...
Thats emberassing ;). I change so much that I forgot about that.